# Instagram API get notified on new followers

Tags: api, notifications, instagram

Today I had an idea. I want to make a light switch on when I get a new follower on my Instagram account.

I know some APIs to switch on the light, but I'm looking for a way to get notified on new followers. So I searched on Instagram documentation but I only found webhooks for mentions and stories.

Do you know if there is a web to get notified on a new follower to call the light API?

Comment: I'm asking the same thing. And i don't want massive informations like the entire list. Just getting notified when the user gets a new follower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instagram does not provide a webhook endpoint for follower events. It provides support for changes to the comments, mentions, and story_insights fields as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/webhooks/#set-up-endpoint-and-product).

Answer (score 1):

The link has changed and the new link for the documentation on this is here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/webhooks#step-1--create-an-endpoint-and-configure-the-webhooks-product

But dmulter is right, they don't seem to have this ability. you can make webhooks for comments, mentions, and story insights

also you can get webhooks on instagram messages through facebook messenger api. here is some documentation on this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook#events

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at Webhooks. I’m using webhooks to get notifications about new like on my facebook page. Instagram has webhooks to. But I didn’t read the documentation.